# Routing error in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am certainly losing my head/sleep over this. 
This is my questions_controller.rb

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /questions
  # GET /questions.json
  def index
    @questions = Question.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @questions }
    end
  end
```

This is my applications_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

This is my rake routes:

```
    questions GET    /questions(.:format)          questions#index
              POST   /questions(.:format)          questions#create
 new_question GET    /questions/new(.:format)      questions#new
edit_question GET    /questions/:id/edit(.:format) questions#edit
     question GET    /questions/:id(.:format)      questions#show
              PUT    /questions/:id(.:format)      questions#update
              DELETE /questions/:id(.:format)      questions#destroy
   home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)         home#index
```

This is my routes.rb

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :questions
end
```

Error on going to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/questions`

```
uninitialized constant QuestionsController
```

What might be the error?

Comment: Is the missing 'end' in your questions_controller.rb a cut and paste error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of errors sometimes happen when there is a syntax error in one of files. Restart your dev server and look up for errors in its output.

Especially check line

```
format.html # index.html.erb
```

I don't think it can be written this way.

Comment: The `# index.html.erb` is a comment. That line looks fine to me.

Comment: I know it's a comment, but there should be a block `{ ... }` instead of this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure the controller filename is in correctly plural form?

```
app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
```

Thanks.